# Unable to compile C++ program on a macosx: error: unknown type name 'constexpr'

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, constexpr

I am trying to compile the below program. However it's giving me the `error: unknown type name 'constexpr'` error. What should I do?

Code:

```
//this is model.cpp. battery.cpp and load.cpp are two secondary files
#include "load.h"
#include "battery.h"

//compile time constants - Settings
constexpr int intervals = 96;
constexpr float e_min = 0.001;
constexpr int max_iters = 100;
constexpr int nloads = 10;
constexpr int nbat = 10;


struct devices
{
    load loadDevices[nloads];
    battery batteryDevices[nbat];
};

int main()
{


    //Initialization of the model
    devices devices1;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the same error on each line where constexpr is used.

```
error: unknown type name 'constexpr'
constexpr int intervals = 96;
```

My C/C++ configurations .json file is as follows:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-11",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

System: MACOSX

IDE: VSCode

Compiling on Mac's Terminal using g++

compilation command: `g++ model.cpp battery.cpp load.cpp`

Comment: `-std=c++11`/14/17/20 ?

Comment: Hi Jarod,I am a beginner programmer in C++. Are you saying I should type `g++ -std=c++11 model.cpp battery.cpp load.cpp` in the mac terminal to compile?

Comment: Yes (even use more recent standard if possible). Giving version of gcc might help else.

Comment: Okay. The constexpr error goes away when I compile with -std=c++11 and onwards. However now post compiling I get the `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` error for the method `"optAlg::bufferPlanning(float*, float, float, int, float*, float*, float, float, float*, float*, bool, float*, int, float*, float*)", referenced from:
      battery::plan(float*) in battery-011c04.o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That json config is not used if you are calling the compiler directly from the command line. In that case you have to specify every option yourself:

```
g++ -std=gnu++17 -Wall -Werror model.cpp battery.cpp load.cpp
```

I just added `-Wall -Werror` for good measure, you should never compile your code without them.

Without the `-std` option the compiler uses an older version of the C++ standard that does not have `constexpr`.